# CruiseControl.NET: using $(CCNetLabel ) inside ccnet.config file

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

When calling external processes like MSBuild cruise control sets environment variables. One of values is CCNetLabel. it holds the value of the current projects label. I want to use the same values in ccnet config itself but when I try ccnet config has a problem. I get the following error:

```
[CCNet Server:ERROR] INTERNAL ERROR: Reference to unknown symbol CCNetLabel
----------
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Config.Preprocessor.EvaluationException: Reference to unknown symbol CCNetLabel
at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Config.Preprocessor.ConfigPreprocessorEnvironment._GetConstantDef(String name)
at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Config.Preprocessor.ConfigPreprocessorEnvironment.eval_text_constant(String name)

.....

----------
```

I actually want to append the CCNetLabel to another variable so I need to access the property in ccnet.config.

is there a different way to reference these variables?

Answer (score 21):

We had a need to do this too, and found that we could use [Replacement Dynamic Values](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Replacement_Dynamic_Value), introduced in CruiseControl.NET 1.5, to access the **CCNetLabel** from within ccnet.config.

For example, the **dynamicValues** block in this snippet:

```
  <buildpublisher>
    <sourceDir>C:\ccnet_projects\Installer\bin\x86\Release</sourceDir>
    <dynamicValues>
      <replacementValue property="publishDir">
        <format>C:\builds\installers\{0}\x86</format>
        <parameters>
          <namedValue name="$CCNetLabel" value="Default" />
        </parameters>
      </replacementValue>
    </dynamicValues>
    <useLabelSubDirectory>false</useLabelSubDirectory>
  </buildpublisher>
```

Produces a **publishDir** path containing the **CCNetLabel** value on the fly:

```
  <buildpublisher>
    <sourceDir>C:\ccnet_projects\Installer\bin\x86\Release</sourceDir>
    <publishDir>C:\builds\installers\1.0.2.120\x86</publishDir>
    <useLabelSubDirectory>false</useLabelSubDirectory>
  </buildpublisher>
```

(Note that for this particular example, **useLabelSubDirectory** is set to false to avoid appending the **CCNetLabel** to the **publishDir** path.)

Answer (score 15):

The following can be used in config file in ccnet version 1.5
< cb:define buildversion="$[**$CCNetLabel**]" />

Comment: This works. I put this one after the labeller type. and used $(buildversion) and it got substituted correctly.

Answer (score 9):

I think Darryl's answer is the best approach to solve this problem in CCNET 1.5.
Just two comments about the answer:

- This is the right link to ccnet docs about [Dynamic Parameters](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Dynamic+Parameters).
- As you can read in the docs, there is a shortcut to obtain just the value of the integration property you are looking for using the syntax `$[$Integration_Property]`. In your case, using `$[$CCNetLabel]` would work.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way of accessing these environment variables inside CCNET configuration. I think almost anybody who configured CCNET (including myself) has tried to do so. This feature has been requested often, but it hasn't been implemented yet.

If you want access to `CCNetWorkingDirectory` or `CCNetArtifactDirectory` there is a workaround:

```
<cb:define name="project.workingDirectory">c:/foo</cb:define>
<cb:define name="project.artifactDirectory">c:/bar</cb:define>
<project>
  <workingDirectory>$(project.workingDirectory)</workingDirectory>
  <artifactDirectory>$(project.artifactDirectory)</artifactDirectory>
  ...
</project>
```

But I'm not aware of a solution for accessing `CCNetLabel`. Sorry, I don't have better news.

Answer (score 5):

The following articles should be able to help you.  You may be able to use `cb:scope`, or defining your whole project in a `cb:define` and pass the project name in.

-Good luck-

http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Configuration+Preprocessor

http://ferventcoder.com/archive/2009/05/21/uppercut---automated-builds---cruisecontrol.net-integration.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I've solved this by adding an msbuild task in the publisher section (including the `CCNetLabel` in the path)

```xml
<msbuild>
    <executable>c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
    <workingDirectory>C:\Path\WebApp</workingDirectory>
    <projectFile>WebApp.csproj</projectFile>
    <dynamicValues>
        <replacementValue property="buildArgs">
            <format>/noconsolelogger /v:quiet /p:Configuration=Release /p:WebProjectOutputDir=c:\Publish\WebApp\{0}\ /p:OutDir=c:\Publish\WebApp\{0}\bin\</format>
            <parameters>
                <namedValue name="$CCNetLabel" value="Default" />
            </parameters>
        </replacementValue>
    </dynamicValues>                    
    <targets>ResolveReferences;_CopyWebApplication</targets>
    <timeout>600</timeout>              
</msbuild>
```

Answer (score 2):

if using version 1.5 then you can directly specify $(CCNetLabel) in the msbuild task

```
 
<msbuild>
 <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe</executable>
 <workingDirectory>C:\TestApp\WindowsFormsApplication1</workingDirectory>
 <projectFile>WindowsFormsApplication1.sln</projectFile>
 <buildArgs>/p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any Cpu" /p:AssemblyVersion=$(CCNetLabel) </buildArgs>
 <targets>build</targets>
 <logger>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
</msbuild>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do this as well and just ended up using a NANT script, where I can get to `CCNetLabel` as an environment variabl like so:

```
  <property name="version.build" value="${environment::get-variable('CCNetLabel')}"/>
```