# CruiseControl.Net - Use of parameters in ccnet.config

Tags: parameters, cruisecontrol.net, mstest

I'm trying to use the **CCNetBuildDate** and **CCNetBuildTime** parameters to dynamically change the output filename of my unit test results, so for example:

```
<project>
       <workingDirectory>C:\MyProject</workingDirectory>
  <tasks>
    <msbuild>
      <buildArgs>/property:TestResultsFile=TestResults.$[CCNetBuildDate].$[CCNetBuildTime].trx</buildArgs>
      <!-- etc... -->
    </msbuild>
  </tasks>

  <publishers>
    <merge>
      <files>
        <file>TestResults.$[CCNetBuildDate].$[CCNetBuildTime].trx</file>
      </files>
    </merge>
    <xmllogger />
  </publishers>
</project>
```

The trouble is that I cant figure out the syntax for using parameters in this way - I've tried dozens of variations:

- $(CCNetBuildTime)
- ${CCNetBuildTime}
- $CCNetBuildTime

But it never seems to actually pass the build time as the parameter (so for example in the above case I ended up with a filename "TestResults.$[CCNetBuildDate].$[CCNetBuildTime].trx"

What am I doing wrong?

(FYI: The reason I'm trying to dynamically decide the test results filename is because with a fixed results filename I kept on having the results from past builds included in my build report)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short: You can't access integration properties like `CCNetBuildDate` inside your CCNET configuration.

Find my answers on similar questions: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080498/cruisecontrol-net-ccnetworkingdirectory-parameter-problem/3082543#3082543), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563362/cruisecontrol-net-using-ccnetlabel-inside-ccnet-config-file/1564664#1564664), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592059/how-to-pass-an-integration-property-to-a-batch-file-with-cruisecontrolnet/2594403#2594403).

Since the same question arises again and again, it seems to be absolutely intuitive to use the integration properties this way. So it perhaps would be worth making it a CCNET feature request...