# CruiseControl.Net CCNetWorkingDirectory parameter problem

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I'm working with the latest CruiseControl.Net 1.5.7256.1.
I'm trying to use one of the system parameters, *CCNetWorkingDirectory* under *sourcecontrol* block and the project failed to recognize this parameter.

```
<sourcecontrol type="svn">
    <trunkUrl>https://padev/svn/physical/Source</trunkUrl>
    <workingDirectory>$[CCNetWorkingDirectory]\SVN\Source</workingDirectory>
    <username>ccnet</username>
    <password>hidden</password>
</sourcecontrol>
```

I also tried it as $CCNetWorkingDirectory, $(CCNetWorkingDirectory), Non of these option worked.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got trapped. I think almost anybody who starts with CCNET tries to access `CCNetWorkingDirectory` inside CCNET configuration. This is not possible. Find my answer on a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563362/cruisecontrol-net-using-ccnetlabel-inside-ccnet-config-file/1564664#1564664).

Comment: Brilliant. Someone should update their documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in which version things changed but as of version 1.8 you can use what they call: System Paremeters as documented here:

http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Dynamic+Parameters

and it works for me as in this sample configuration:

```
<project name="ProjectName" queue="myqueue" queuePriority="1">
    <workingDirectory>path</workingDirectory>
    ...

    <sourcecontrol type="svn">
        <workingDirectory>$[$CCNetWorkingDirectory]</workingDirectory>
        ...
    </sourcecontrol>
```